# cron and at are not working

Tags: macos, unix, cron, at

On my Mac (yeah, yeah I know. but my Linux box is at work) for some reason `cron` and `at` don't want to work. They both register that jobs have been added, with no syntax errors or any qualms at all. Then the time passes, and neither do anything.

`52 18 * * * username touch ~/webserver/AAAAA`

That should have run at 6:52PM PST, but it never did. Why?

For `at`, I did: `at 6:48 pm < jobs` where `jobs` looks like:

```
touch ~/webserver/AAAAA
```

And nothing happened. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in your mailbox with `mail`?  You will probably find error messages from `cron` there.  I found my expected error when I set `cron` going before I created the script for it to run.  One useful bit of information was the environment settings - which are often relevant to these problems.  I got the information:

```
Message 1:
From jleffler@Isis.local  Thu Jan 12 20:16:01 2012
X-Original-To: jleffler
Delivered-To: jleffler@Isis.local
From: jleffler@Isis.local (Cron Daemon)
To: jleffler@Isis.local
Subject: Cron <jleffler@Isis> /bin/ksh /Users/jleffler/bin/Cron/minutely
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=jleffler>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=jleffler>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/jleffler>
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2012 20:16:00 -0800 (PST)

/Users/jleffler/bin/Cron/minutely[15]: exec: /work1/jleffler/bin/minutely: not found
```

This from an entry:

```
*        *       *       *       *       /bin/ksh /Users/jleffler/bin/Cron/minutely
```

The other issue I see is your command line:

```
52 18 * * * username touch ~/webserver/AAAAA
```

What is the `username` command?  It isn't something I find on my Mac (MacOS X 10.7.2).  Is it in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` on your machine?  If not, the chances are high that it won't be found.

The `/Users/jleffler/bin/Cron/minutely` script on my machine is a (symlink to a) script that reads a profile - I call mine `.cronfile` - and then executes a command `/Users/jleffler/bin/minutely`, all based on the basename of the file in the `Cron` directory.  This sets my PATH to something more useful than the system PATH provided by `cron`.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! And for some reason my `cron` manpage says to put my username in that field. Thank you for answering! What about `at`?

Comment: For the format of `crontab` entries, try `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: @tekknolagi: For 'at', I note that `man at` includes: _IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
     Note that at is implemented through the launchd(8) daemon periodically invoking atrun(8), which is disabled by default.  See atrun(8) for information about enabling atrun._   When I tried on my system, `at` queued the job OK, but the jobs did not run.  That was when I really read the man page!  (When I did what `man atrun` said, my previously queued `at` requests ran at the next minute boundary.)

Comment: Thank you JonathanLeffler! seems you also helped me on my Perl code :)

Answer (score 1):

My bet - is that the path for cron is not inclusive enough to include touch - either add a path directive to the cron or use a fully qualified path for touch

Comment: Okay, just tried with `/Users/username/webserver/` instead of the `~` path but that doesn't work either. Why?

Comment: So what's wrong? :(

Comment: Not sure about Mac but un9's have a /var/log/cron.log file which may have more info

Comment: No such file :(

Comment: Sorry - out of ideas - hopefully expert here can help

Comment: Hopefully they can